# O modal form aparece bagunçado

Tags: html, css, formulário, login, modal

preciso de uma ajudinha. Meu modal form aparece bagunçado quando ponho dentro do meu projeto. Por outro lado, quando eu crio uma página separada, ele aparece perfeitamente como deveria estar. Segue o código:

```css
input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.cancelbtn {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  padding: 15px;
}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  / padding-top: 60px;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 5% auto 15% auto;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .cancelbtn {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="id01" class="modal">
  <form class="modal-content animate">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span class="close" title="sair">&times;</span>
      <img src="img/users.png" alt="users" class="avatar">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <label for="uname"><b>E-mail</b></label>
      <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Entre com o seu e-mail" required>
      <label for="psw"><b>Senha</b></label>
      <input type="password" name="psw" placeholder="insira sua senha">
      <button type="submit">Entrar</button>
      <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="lembrar" checked="checked">Lembre-ne
            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="background-color: #f1f1f1">
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancelar</button>
      <span class="psw">Esqueceu a <a href="">senha?</a></span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="cancelbtn">Exibir modal</button>
```

Comment: Por favor, adicione o trecho de código em que a modal fica bagunçada, pra entendermos qual o problema!

Comment: Pelo executar está parecendo normal o form.

Comment: Cara vc não está usando classes com os mesmos nomes, mas em lugares diferentes? Provavelmente o que está acontecendo é sobreposição de estilos, então provavelmente vc tem classes com o mesmo nome e estilos diferentes algo assim.